# BL class and DAL class not found

Tags: c#

My DAL File is

```
public class dalEmployeeInformation
{
    public string MyProperty_EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string MyProperty_EmpFirstName { get; set; }
    public string MyProperty_EmpLastName { get; set; }

    public string MyProperty_Exception { get; set; }

    private DataSet dsEmployee =  new DataSet();
    public DataSet MyProperty_dsEmployee 
    {
        get { return dsEmployee; }
        set { dsEmployee = value; }
    }

    private DataTable dtEmployee = new DataTable();
    public DataTable MyProperty_dtEmployee
    {
        get { return dtEmployee;}
        set { dtEmployee = value; } 
    }
```

}

This is how i used it to save

```
    public void AddEmployee(dalEmployeeInformation obj)
    {
        try
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "addEmployee";

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpID", obj.MyProperty_EmployeeID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", obj.MyProperty_EmpFirstName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", obj.MyProperty_EmpLastName);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();                               
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            obj.MyProperty_Exception = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

and This is how I used it to retrieve data.

```
    public dalEmployeeInformation ViewSelectedEmployee(dalEmployeeInformation obj)
    {
        try
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "getSelectedEmployeeInfo";

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpID", obj.MyProperty_EmployeeID);
            ada.Fill(obj.MyProperty_dsEmployee , "SelectedEmployee");
            ada.Fill(obj.MyProperty_dtEmployee );
            return obj;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            obj.MyProperty_Exception = ex.Message;
            return obj;
        }
    }
```

In the form.cs

```
    private void AddEmployee()
    {
        blEmployeeInformation bl = new blEmployeeInformation();
        dalEmployeeInformation dal = new dalEmployeeInformation();
        dal.MyProperty_Exception = "";

        dal.MyProperty_EmployeeID = txtEmployeeID.Text;
        dal.MyProperty_EmpFirstName = txtEmpFirstName.Text;
        dal.MyProperty_EmpLastName = txtEmpLastName.Text;

        bl.AddEmployee(dal);

        if (dal.MyProperty_Exception == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Employee Added Successfully");
        }
        else

        {
            MessageBox.Show("Employee not Added");
        }

    }
```

But when I try to debug it's coming this error messages

> Error    3   The type or namespace name 'dalEmployeeInformation' could not
>   be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Error 2   The type or namespace name 'blEmployeeInformation' could not
>   be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I think the error message is pretty clear. `are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on "References" folder in solution explorer and click on "add references" then refer BL and DAL folders (projects).

Then add there two lines to the form.cs file

```
using BL;
using DAL;
```